# How does Java 8 mapToInt ( mapToInt(e -> e) )improves performance exactly?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading the book "Java 8 Lambdas", and at some point the author says "It’s a good idea to use the primitive specialized functions wherever possible because of
the performance benefits.".

He is referring here to mapToInt, mapToLong, etc.

The thing is I don't know where the performance comes from to be honest.

Let's consider an example:

```
    // Consider this a very very long list, with a lot of elements
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

    //sum it, flavour 1
    int sum1 = list.stream().reduce(0, (acc, e) -> acc + e).intValue();

    //sum it, flavour 2
    int sum2 = list.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).sum();

    System.out.println(sum1 + " " + sum2);
```

So, in the first case I use reduce to sum the values, so the BinaryOperator function will receive all the time an int ( acc ) and an Integer ( the current element of the collection ) and then will do an unboxing of the Integer to the int ( acc + e)

In the second case, I use mapToInt, which unboxes each Integer into an int, and then sums it.

My question is, is there any advantage of the second approach?
Also what's the point of map to int, when I could have used map?

So yeah, is it all just sugar syntax or does it has some performance benefits? In case it does, please offer some information

Regards,

Comment: works with primitive which is an advantage, collections api typically work with the corresponding Object counterparts which is thus avoided

Comment: yes, but to me the number of unboxing is the same. That's why I don't see where's the advantage comes from

Comment: If you strive for the last bit of performance you should prefer `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` over `mapToInt(e -> e)`.

Comment: @Holger Aren't they equivalent? `e -> e` is performing an implicit unboxing operation, which delegates to Integer.intValue, anyway

Comment: @Alexander yes, it will compile to code delegating to `intValue()`, whereas `Integer::intValue` will evaluate to a function that invokes `intValue()` directly without that delegation. They *are* equivalent, there’s just a tiny (really tiny) performance difference due to saving one level of delegation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's an extra level of boxing going on in

```
int sum1 = list.stream().reduce(0, (acc, e) -> acc + e).intValue();
```

as the reduction function is a `BinaryOperator<Integer>` - it gets passed two `Integer` values, unboxes them, adds them, and then re-boxes the result.  The `mapToInt` version unboxes the `Integer` elements from the list *once* and then works with primitive `int` values from that point on as an `IntStream`.

Comment: +1. This is even more important when there are more operations chained after the map (filtering, reducing, other transformations), which will all need to unbox and then rebox.

Comment: Ah yes, I kind of forgot that acc is also Integer :) Thank you for pointing that out Ian, Also JB you are correct regarding other operation applied afterwards