# Java map an array of Strings to an array of Integers

Tags: java, java-8, integer, java-stream

I found this code on SO to map strings to ints

```
Arrays.stream(myarray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

But how do I make it map to Integer type not the primitive int?

I tried switching from `Integer.parseInt` to `Integer.valueOf`, but it seems that the `mapToInt()` method forces the primitive type.

I have an ArrayList of arrays of Integers, so I cannot use primitive ints.

Comment: The `Integer` class is the same thing as an `int` really. It wraps and unwraps an  `int` for you, so, hypothetically, they are the same

Comment: Yes, but this method shows an error "The method add(Integer[]) in the type ArrayList<Integer[]> is not applicable for the arguments (int[])" when I try to append the mapped array to my ArrayList of Integers.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269346/how-does-java-8-maptoint-maptointe-e-improves-performance-exactly) seems relevant to your doubt.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since `String` and `Integer` are both reference types you can simply call `Stream::map` to transform your array.

```
Integer[] boxed = Stream.of(myarray).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use the [`Stream<Integer> boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) method.

> [`Stream<Integer> boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) returns a Stream consisting of the elements of
>   this stream, each *boxed* to an Integer.

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();
resultSet.add(Arrays.stream(myarray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to do it more elegantly, though? Like for example in JavaScript myarray.map(function(e) {return parseInt(e);});? It seems like a lot of nested calls and intermediate types for just a simple String[] to Integer[] conversion.

Comment: You can `map` instead of `box`ing and `mapInt`:


 `String [] myArray = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};`
  `Integer[] integerList =Arrays.stream(myArray).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new); 
 
System.out.print(integerList[0].getClass()); //output: class java.lang.Integer`