# How to cast Object[] into int[] in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, casting, priority-queue

After I use the method `.toArray()` in a Priority Queue of Integers I get an array of Objects like this:

```java
Object[] objects = pq.toArray();
```

However, I need the array to be `int[]`. I've tried:

```java
int [] arr = (int[]) objects;
```

but it says:

```
Cannot cast from Object[] to int[]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All collections provide an alternative `toArray` implementation specifying the element type:

```java
Integer[] objects = pq.toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

**Note this requires Java v11 or higher**

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)

Note the resultant array is obviously integer *wrapper* objects in this case, don't know if that's fine for your requirements.

EDIT - quick test:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>();
q.add(42);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(q.toArray(Integer[]::new)));
```

Comment: The method toArray(T[]) in the type PriorityQueue<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer[]::new)

Comment: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

Comment: Incompatible parameter list for array constructor. Expected (int), but found ()

Comment: Those are the 3 error messages I get when I use that expression.

Comment: @PabloBiedma Please post the declaration of your queue.  Your post implied it was `PriorityQueue<Integer>`?

Comment: PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();

Comment: Added test code to my answer, looks exactly the same as yours, wierd.  You're using Java v8+ yes?

Comment: @stridecolossus You current solution can't work: there are two `toArray`s. The first one, from the `Collection` interface, requires a target array to be provided, say `q.toArray(new Integer[q.size()])`. The second one, from the `BaseStream` interface, requires a factory method to create an array for the given length, say `q.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new)`. You mixed both into one, thus it's not working.

Comment: @fluffy Nothing to do with streams, it's a default method on the base collection class: 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#toArray(T[]).  Also note there are two implementations.

Comment: @stridecolossus That is a part of what I'm talking about. Please re-read. Your code cannot compile because of mixing ideas from both `toArray`s. You've been confused with this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-

Comment: @fluffy Try the code, it compiles and runs, that's exactly what I did!  Example from the JavaDoc doing exactly that: `String[] y = x.toArray(String[]::new)`.  Also note the default implementation **delegates** to the other `toArray` implementation.

Comment: @stridecolossus Do you realize that `x.toArray(new String[0]);` (from the example) is not the same as `x.toArray(String[]::new)`? Again, `javac` rejects your solution marked as "quick test" with  `error: no suitable method found for toArray(Integer[]::new)`.

Comment: @fluffy @Pablo Biedma What version of Java are you using?  The `toArray` implementation I used in the snippet above is `@since 11`.  If you're using an older version then obviously that method doesn't exist hence the error.

Comment: @stridecolossus Sorry, didn't figured out that you're referring to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction) since Java 11 (I'm still in the Java 8 world, and having new methods like that in very old interfaces passes by me). That now makes sense.

Comment: @fluffy Yeah I just realised I posted old version of JavaDoc to confused matters even more, duh!  Modified answer accordingly.

Comment: @stridecolossus Again, apologies for that. I'm aware of post-8 Java releases, but usually don't pay much attention on API changes, especially those that affect old APIs, but pay more attention on language changes. So this is where my "ancientness" from the world of Java 8 played for misinterpretation. I was really confused with the old Javadoc 7 reference, so it made me think there was a typo mixing up the things. Have a nice day and thanks for putting the "Java 11+" notice to your answer!

Comment: @fluffy No worries, I was as confused as you I expect!  Apologies for posting the 'ancient' JavaDoc link which just made things even more confused.  We got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can easily do.

You might know that the Object[] is actually just full of integers, which would mean that it should be possible to cast it, right?

Problem is, the variable "objects" still exists. And in an Object[] you're allowed to put any Object. So after your cast, someone might do something like:

```
objects[0] = "some string";
```

So what should happen then? Should your int[] suddenly be invalid since it now contains a String? Should it not be allowed to input things other than Integers into `objects` which typically allows that?

Casting just means you point to the same thing but look at it differently. What you need to do is to transform it. For that there's already an answer:

[java-map-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877296/java-map-an-array-of-strings-to-an-array-of-integers)

So, simple casting is not going to help out here.

Update: @stridecolossus answer is probably just as good as the one I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) implements [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), you can use a [`stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) to iterate over its elements and map them to `int`:

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5));

int[] arr = pq.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [1, 2, 5]
```